# Unable to determine the correct call signature - multiple procedures/functions/signatures error while using simpleJdbcCall

Tags: oracle, spring-mvc, spring-jdbc

Here is my DAO code

```
 this.calcRTRDetails = new SimpleJdbcCall(dataSource).withCatalogName("score_rtr").
                     withProcedureName("calc_rtr_dtls").declareParameters(
                        new SqlParameter("p_repy_track", Types.ARRAY)    
                      ).returningResultSet("p_track_dtls",new RowMapper<String>() {

                        @Override
                        public String mapRow(ResultSet rs, int arg1)
                                throws SQLException {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            return rs.getString(1);
                        }
                    } );
```

I get the following error

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Unable to determine the correct call signature - multiple procedures/functions/signatures for CALC_RTR_DTLS found [SCORE_RTR.SCORE.CALC_RTR_DTLS, SCORE_RTR.SCORE.CALC_RTR_DTLS]
```

What can be the reason  ??

Comment: Is it really called "p_repy_track" in line 3?

Comment: It could be that your JDBC user doesn't have privileges on that package/function/table or whatever...

Answer (score 7):

I found that I had a very similar issue where I was trying to call an overloaded Postgres function. The solution in Spring 3.2.3 was to call withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess().

But be sure to explicitly declare your parameters. Alternative is to to give your overloaded functions different names.